# Removing or hiding WooCommerce "Return to Shop" button from 'empty cart' page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've been trying to remove the "Return to Shop" button from the WooCommerce 'empty cart' page, but without much luck. Closest I've found is the snippet below from 2015, which did work for someone back in the day, but doesn't work for me now. Does anyone know why, or have a better way?

```
.empty-cart-block .button.active {
display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: `.woocommerce-cart .return-to-shop { display: none !important; }` 
should suffice

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use this simple line of CSS code:

```
.woocommerce-cart .return-to-shop { display: none !important; };
```

Code goes in styles.css file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Return to shop button in WooCommerce shop page, copy the template file located in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart` to your child-theme like `/wp-content/themes/childtheme/woocommerce` and simply delete the button.

Answer (score 0):

It will hide, not remove:

```
a.button.wc-backward {
display: none;
}
```